# Mac Mail reducing image size making it unreadable to the recipient

Tags: mail.app

As per the title, when I send an email to someone with an image attached. Mail is reducing the image size making it barely legible.

The workaround is to add the image to a pdf.

I have looked around for a solution however I am unable to figure out where and how to tell mac mail not to nanny my images!

Any help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I figured this out, there are actually a number of options:

1. If you are using inline images, when you add an image, there is actually a drop down menu just below the from address which states "image size", use that to size the image accordingly.
2. If you switch off inline images:

   defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool YES

This will send the image in the current size.

Well, there we go!